# Removing duplicate values from a timeseries in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, duplicates, time-series, unique, interpolation

I have a timeseries that looks like this:

```
Time    Data
-------------
802     1
803     2
803     3
804     7
```

I want to use `interp(x,v,xq)` with x as the time and v as the data, but that function requires me to have distinct x values. How do I remove/average duplicate rows in a MATLAB timeseries?

I tried `interp(unique(timeseriesname.time), timeseriesname.data, timeseriesref.time)`

But this mismatches my data. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Would the [`resample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.resample.html) method work for you? `newSeries = resample(timeseriesname, timeseriesref.time);` Granted, for the given example it would have a discontinuity around time point `803`, so it may not be what you need.

Comment: Maybe. I have a lot of data and only a few duplicates so this might work. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the interpolation to work on the data as-is, you could try the [`resample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.resample.html) method for [`timeseries`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.html) objects. Granted, for your given example, it will display a discontinuity around time point `803`, but it will still work without error:

```
>> ts = timeseries([1 2 3 7].', [802 803 803 804]);
>> rs = resample(ts, 802:0.25:804);
>> [rs.time rs.data]

ans =

  802.0000    1.0000
  802.2500    1.2500
  802.5000    1.5000
  802.7500    1.7500
  803.0000    3.0000
  803.2500    4.0000
  803.5000    5.0000
  803.7500    6.0000
  804.0000    7.0000
```

Notice how time point `803` has the value `3`, but interpolants approach the value `2` from below.

If you'd rather just remove the duplicate entries by averaging them, you could use the functions [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to create a new `timeseries` object like so:

```
>> [newTime, ~, index] = unique(ts.time);
>> newTS = timeseries(accumarray(index, ts.data, [], @mean), newTime);
>> [newTS.time newTS.data]

ans =

  802.0000    1.0000
  803.0000    2.5000
  804.0000    7.0000
```

Alternatively, if you'd like to modify the time and data of the *original* `timeseries` object, you can set them simultaneously with the [`set`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.set.html) method:

```
[newTime, ~, index] = unique(ts.time);
newData = accumarray(index, ts.data, [], @mean);
set(ts, 'Time', newTime, 'Data', newData);
```

Comment: The second solution is very close to what I want. Is there a way to append/modify the previous Ts so that the properties of the newTS and oldTS are the same without iterating through every property?

Comment: @Sunden: I added an option for modifying the original `timeseries` object.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I wanted, thanks. You've saved me a lot of time.